# Different cell events for table cell in iTexsharp pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, cell

I have a requirement wherein in a calendar I need to set different image as per the business logic. The calendar is created using pdfpTable , referred the link : http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext_calendar.aspx to create my custom calendar.

There is a dataset having Date & Status which needs to be checked against each date in Calendar. Example if Date is 1 and Status is GOOD then add image1 else
if Date is 1 and Status is NONCOMM then add image2.

I have created different cell events for all the images, but for all the cells its assigning the same image. While debugging its showing different Cell events is getting set but final output in pdf is showing all cells in table with same event.

The complete code is below that I am using also attaching ImageExpected ( the commented code output) and ImageError result with below code, appreciate if I get any assistance where I am wrong.

This is I am expecting : [ImageExpected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgbdw.jpg)

This is what I am getting : [Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd1jE.jpg)

DataTable listStatus is having column Date & Status

Date        Status
1/7/2018    GOOD
2/7/2018    PMCREATED
3/7/2018    NONCOMM
.....
30/7/2018   GOOD

```
   private void CreateCalendar(DataTable listStatus)
    {
        CalculateDates(currentYear, currentMonth);
        IntializeHeadings();
        float height = 40f;
        PdfPCell day = new PdfPCell();
        day.PaddingTop = 0;

        GoodEvent GoodEvent = new GoodEvent();
        PMCreatedEvent PMCreatedEvent = new PMCreatedEvent();
        UMRemoteEvent UMRemoteEvent = new UMRemoteEvent();
        UMFieldEvent UMFieldEvent = new UMFieldEvent();
        PMPerformedEvent PMPerformedEvent = new PMPerformedEvent();
        NonCommEvent NonCommEvent = new NonCommEvent();

        int count = 0;
        int dayCounter = 0;

        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < calRows; ++i)
            {
                // set fixed row height
                day.FixedHeight = height;

                int y = listStatus.Rows.Count;

                for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
                {
                   string daynum = count >= firstOffsOfmonth && count < (firstOffsOfmonth + daysinMonth) ? (++dayCounter).ToString() : "";

                    // This commented code is working and setting properly the cell event
                    //if (daynum != "" && dayCounter <= DateTime.Now.Day)
                    //{
                    //    day.CellEvent = GoodEvent;
                    //}

                    //else if (daynum != "" && dayCounter==20)
                    //{
                    //    day.CellEvent = PMCreatedEvent;
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    day.CellEvent = null;
                    //}

                    // Below code not working and setting all event as GoodEvent
                    if (listStatus.Rows.Count != 0)
                    {
                        DateTime tranDate = Convert.ToDateTime(listStatus.Rows[0]["Date"].ToString());
                        string tranStatus = listStatus.Rows[0]["Status"].ToString();
                        int tranDay = Convert.ToInt32(tranDate.Day.ToString());

                        if (daynum != "" && dayCounter == tranDay && tranStatus == "GOOD")
                        {
                            day.CellEvent=GoodEvent;
                        }

                        else if (daynum != "" && dayCounter == tranDay && tranStatus == "PMCREATED")
                        {
                            day.CellEvent = PMCreatedEvent;

                        }

                        else if (daynum != "" && dayCounter == tranDay && tranStatus == "UMREMOTE")
                        {
                            day.CellEvent = UMRemoteEvent;
                        }

                       else if (daynum != "" && dayCounter == tranDay && tranStatus == "UMFIELD")
                        {
                            day.CellEvent = UMFieldEvent;
                        }

                        else if (daynum != "" && dayCounter == tranDay && tranStatus == "PMPERFORMED")
                        {
                            day.CellEvent = PMPerformedEvent;
                        }

                         else if (daynum != "" && dayCounter == tranDay && tranStatus == "NONCOMM")
                        {
                            day.CellEvent = NonCommEvent;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            day.CellEvent = null;
                        }
                        listStatus.Rows[0].Delete(); // Deleting the table so that after 7 days its goes to next row of table
                        listStatus.AcceptChanges();

                    }
                    day.Phrase = new Phrase(daynum, fontday);
                    pTableCal.AddCell(day);
                    ++count;

                }

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error encountered " + ex);
        }
    }


      private class GoodEvent: IPdfPCellEvent
    {
        Image imgGoodIcon = Image.GetInstance(imgGood);
        public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
        {
            PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
            // set exact coordinates for ColumnText
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(
              position.Left + 2,  // lower-left x; add some padding
              position.Bottom,    // lower-left y
              position.Right,     // upper-right x
              position.Top        // upper-right x; adjust for existing content
                  - cellLeading - 3
            );

            this.imgGoodIcon.ScaleToFit(25f, 25f);
            this.imgGoodIcon.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            ct.AddElement(this.imgGoodIcon);
            ct.Go();
        }
    }


     private class PMCreatedEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
    {
        Image imgPMCreatedIcon = Image.GetInstance(imgPMCreated);
        public void CellLayout(
          PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases
        )
        {

            PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
            // set exact coordinates for ColumnText
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(
              position.Left + 2,  // lower-left x; add some padding
              position.Bottom,    // lower-left y
              position.Right,     // upper-right x
              position.Top        // upper-right x; adjust for existing content
                  - cellLeading - 3
            );
            imgPMCreatedIcon.ScaleToFit(25f, 25f);
            imgPMCreatedIcon.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            ct.AddElement(imgPMCreatedIcon);
            ct.Go();
        }
    }


    private class UMRemoteEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
    {
        Image imgUmRemoteIcon = Image.GetInstance(imgUmRemote);
        public void CellLayout(
          PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases
        )
        {

            PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
            // set exact coordinates for ColumnText
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(
              position.Left + 2,  // lower-left x; add some padding
              position.Bottom,    // lower-left y
              position.Right,     // upper-right x
              position.Top        // upper-right x; adjust for existing content
                  - cellLeading - 3
            );
            imgUmRemoteIcon.ScaleToFit(25f, 25f);
            imgUmRemoteIcon.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            ct.AddElement(imgUmRemoteIcon);
            ct.Go();
        }
    }

    private class UMFieldEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
    {
        Image imgUmFieldIcon = Image.GetInstance(imgUmField);
        public void CellLayout(
          PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases
        )
        {

            PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
            // set exact coordinates for ColumnText
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(
              position.Left + 2,  // lower-left x; add some padding
              position.Bottom,    // lower-left y
              position.Right,     // upper-right x
              position.Top        // upper-right x; adjust for existing content
                  - cellLeading - 3
            );
            imgUmFieldIcon.ScaleToFit(25f, 25f);
            imgUmFieldIcon.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            ct.AddElement(imgUmFieldIcon);
            ct.Go();
        }
    }

    private class PMPerformedEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
    {
        Image imgPmPerformedIcon = Image.GetInstance(imgPmPerformed);
        public void CellLayout(
          PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases
        )
        {

            PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
            // set exact coordinates for ColumnText
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(
              position.Left + 2,  // lower-left x; add some padding
              position.Bottom,    // lower-left y
              position.Right,     // upper-right x
              position.Top        // upper-right x; adjust for existing content
                  - cellLeading - 3
            );
            imgPmPerformedIcon.ScaleToFit(25f, 25f);
            imgPmPerformedIcon.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            ct.AddElement(imgPmPerformedIcon);
            ct.Go();
        }
    }

    private class NonCommEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
    {
        Image imgNonCommIcon = Image.GetInstance(imgNonComm);
        public void CellLayout(
          PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases
        )
        {

            PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
            // set exact coordinates for ColumnText
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(
              position.Left + 2,  // lower-left x; add some padding
              position.Bottom,    // lower-left y
              position.Right,     // upper-right x
              position.Top        // upper-right x; adjust for existing content
                  - cellLeading - 3
            );
            imgNonCommIcon.ScaleToFit(25f, 25f);
            imgNonCommIcon.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            ct.AddElement(imgNonCommIcon);
            ct.Go();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You attached only one image (or probably originally attached two but then somehow lost the image url of one of them). Please add what misses.

Comment: Hi @mkl I have added the Error Image , thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Both images appear to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the goal by resetting the Cellvent after its added to the table, below is the code snippet I have modified. And was able to get the desired Calendar having image as per business logic.[CorrectImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLNNb.png)

Hope this helps anyone who want to achieve similar requirement.

```
 if (listStatus.Rows.Count != 0)
                    {

                        DateTime tranDate = Convert.ToDateTime(listStatus.Rows[0]["TransactionDate"].ToString());
                        string tranStatus = listStatus.Rows[0]["Status"].ToString();
                        int tranDay = Convert.ToInt32(tranDate.Day.ToString());
                        listStatus.Rows[0].Delete();
                        listStatus.AcceptChanges();

                        if (daynum != "" && dayCounter == tranDay && tranStatus == "GOOD")
                        {
                            day.CellEvent=GoodEvent;

                        }

                       if (daynum != "" && dayCounter == tranDay && tranStatus == "PMCREATED")
                        {
                            day.CellEvent = PMCreatedEvent;
                        }

                        if (daynum != "" && dayCounter == tranDay && tranStatus == "UMREMOTE")
                        {
                            day.CellEvent = UMRemoteEvent;
                        }

                        if (daynum != "" && dayCounter == tranDay && tranStatus == "UMFIELD")
                        {
                            day.CellEvent = UMFieldEvent;
                        }

                        if (daynum != "" && dayCounter == tranDay && tranStatus == "PMPERFORMED")
                        {
                            day.CellEvent = PMPerformedEvent;
                        }

                        if (daynum != "" && dayCounter == tranDay && tranStatus == "NONCOMM")
                        {
                            day.CellEvent = NonCommEvent;
                        }

                    }
                    day.Phrase = new Phrase(daynum, fontday);
                    pTableCal.AddCell(day);
                    day.CellEvent = null;
                    ++count;

                }
```